# What hook should I use to define a class?

Tags: hooks

If I want to define a class, like the one below, for a custom module, and make it available to all the functions in my module, which hook should I use?

```
class foo {
  public $bar;
  function display_bar() {
    return $this->bar; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't use a hook to *define* a class, that doesn't really make sense.

If you're talking about autoloading, you have two options:

1. In-built - you can add a file called, for example, foo.class.inc, in your module's root, and add the following to your module's .info file

   ```
   files[] = foo.class.inc
   ```

   Once you've cleared the caches, any time you request a `new foo()`, the appropriate file will automatically be included.

   See [Writing module .info files](https://drupal.org/node/542202) for more information.
2. [XAutoload](https://drupal.org/project/xautoload) - PSR-0 & PSR-4 style autoloading. If you're into OO this is a much better option in my opinion.